# The % symbol shows in the path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using the latest OSX, VSC and Python.  I have the % symbol showing in the path's for the library framework and the python file I'm running.   The only difference I can see would be the OSX.  On another computer running Mojave the % is not in the path.  Below is the output from a simple hello world.

```
%                                                                               
dev@MBP PyRelated % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/dev/Documents/PyRelated/baileytest.py
hello world OKEY dokey
dev@MBP PyRelated %
```

All help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think the `%` is caused by the shell, zsh, not by your program, but it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: as for me it is part of shell's prompt - like `>` in Windows `C:\>` or `$` in Linux `user@computer $` . So you should use Google to find answer for "how to change prompt on OSX"

Comment: Daniel H what other information would be needed?

furas I believe this would be a VSC running on Catalina issue since it doesn't happen on Mojave.  Could be one or the other.  

Thank you both for your replies

Comment: What `baileytest.py` does, primarily. Possibly more detail about how you're running it. Also if there's anything weird about the `%` on the first line, such the text and background color being switched. Honestly, even though in most cases it's less helpful than text, in this particular case a screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: Good Day,  so  Apple changed from Bash to zsh, and that's where the % symbol is coming into play.   You can change back to Bash in OSX and I came across this https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/updating-visual-studio-code-default-terminal-shell-from-bash-to-zsh-711c40d6f8dc so what I'm thinking is change from zsh in OSX and then modify the terminal in VSC to bash also.   I have not come across and article for editing zsh prompts yet.  Thank you for help